# Why is my Navbar Icon not appearing on my website?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am currently teaching myself HTML & CSS, I have bought many books online (hardly read) and I am running into more and more problems. Luckily I have StackOverflow and since you guys helped me out with my last question I thought I should come back and ask another.

All this troubleshooting makes it harder to actually achieve my goal but I am in it for the long run.

I try to write code for at least 2 hours a day while watching tutorials at night. That's my schedule. Once I become more confident in what I am doing then I will put more hours into it.

It's hard to get into the learning process in the beginning, but I know if I keep working hard then anything is possible

So let's solve this,

Thank You!!!!

[Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cKsq14Kfsw&list=PLZiQxHZWe7uam_Po-rJCnXte7OzqDMlfG&index=71&t=426s)
timestamp reference 10:00 - 12:00

[Screenshot of Icon](https://prnt.sc/og1ti2)

Code:

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/gooch/assets/pics/Logo.png"><img src="/gooch/assets/ illustrator/1.png" /></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbarResponsive">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I wanted my logo to appear inside the Navbar.

Comment: You have a space in `/gooch/assets/ illustrator/1.png`.

Comment: Checked it, that's not a space brother.

Answer (score 0):

It could just be a syntactically error in the html? There seems to be a space in your src attribute. If that doesn’t fix it, there is probably an issue in your stylesheet.

Comment: Shouldn't there always be a space in between **image** & **source** ? 
    <img src

Comment: Yes. I am referring to the other space in “assets/ illustrator/“

Answer (score 0):

Lack reputation to comment so will say it here. 
Try to use developer tool of your browser to see the error about your icon

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5kvH.png

then head to "Console" tab

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dhWE.png

you can see here if the image file is missing.